# Include file in excel to use in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using code where a user browses for a specific file that is then written to a text file. Is there a way to include this file in the excel file so it doesn't have to be located. The file is a 4mb kml file.

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
If intChoice <> 0 Then
    newFile = Application.FileDialog( _
        msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
End If


Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(newFile)

Print #1, f.ReadAll

Set f = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
```

Comment: Do you know the exact location of the file, or do you want to read it from a cell?

Comment: The problem is that the location could change, so I was hoping to have it embeded as part of the excel file

Comment: Are you asking to have the contents of the file embedded, as @Roland suggests? The location keeps changing, but does the data change? How do you find the location? Maybe we can teach the macro how to search for it.

Comment: The data does not change, I'm trying to embed it to make it easier to share the excel sheet, that way there won't be two files to keep track off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, Microsoft says `Total number of characters that a cell can contain: 32,767 characters`. What you could do is read the file line by line - using `ReadLine` in a loop instead of ReadAll - into the cells of a hidden sheet, though formatting might get lost. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186118/en